# Alias of a variable in C++/Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, variables, pointers, alias

Is there a way to create an alias of a UI variable in Qt ?

this var

> ui->combobox->currentIndex()

becoming for example

> index

so whenever in my code I call *index* I get the value of *ui->combobox->currentIndex()* even if she changed during two calls.

I tried this but I always get the same value, the one during the initialization.

> int *index = 0;
>   index = (int *)ui->combobox->currentIndex() // equals -1 this time;
>   (int)index; *//always return -1
>   but if I do ui->combobox->currentIndex() it returns 0;*

The goal is to reduce the length of very long statement.
Thanks :)

Comment: What is the return type of `ui->combobox->currentIndex()`?

Comment: int. I'll go for an inline function. No macro for me thanks. Can't take the address of temporary that way.

Comment: You could probably tinker with my little project here ( https://github.com/R3AL/cpProperty ) and get exactly what you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly the best way do do this would be to add an inline function that returns the current index:

```
inline int MainWindow::myIndex() const
{
  return ui->combobox->currentIndex();
}
```

Then you can call `myIndex()` whenever you need the value.

Or simply assign a local variable before the statement you are using it in:

```
int const index = ui->combobox->currentIndex();
```

Comment: I think I will go with inline function. Thanks  
I don't like #define.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the preproccessor macro `#define`

```
#define <alias> <replacement>
```

Is the format you use, then at compile the compiler replaces all instances of your alias.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/

Comment: I'll rather use an inline function.

Comment: As you wish, the compiled code will be equal, they both compile asif you wrote your full ui->...

Comment: @Robadob yes, the generated code will be equal, but macros are the C way to do things. C++ provides a good and type-safe substitute: inlines

Comment: True, I'm just used to complex defines being used for handling compile options. Don't use C/C++ too often.

Comment: Even if Qt is not the best example of good C++ style, don't let people to use bad style

Comment: Ok. That is not a valid argument to use macros. In fact then every trick could then be justified.

Comment: @Robadob and prefer http://en.cppreference.com/w/ instead of cplusplus. Don't understand my comments as a carpet bombing to you. Are only notes to learn good C++ :)

Comment: @Manu343726 Just seem rather mad tbh, I admit inline functions are safer, just preprocessor macros came to mind first. The link was just the first result off Google, no personal preference for C++ docs myself, usually end up in library docs rather than core language. That's how infrequently I use it.

Comment: @Frodo How do you handle the need for different values for certain variables when compiling for different architectures, if not using Macros?

Comment: What I do is to use the macro at one place to define the constant to be later used.